# OpenCV: reconstruct() not found

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am working with QT and I wanted to try the cv::sfm::reconstruct() function from OpenCV. But I can not build it, because they say there is no reconstruct in namespace cv::sfm.

I know that cv::sfm::reconstruct()  is going to be disabled, if I don't have ceres-solver installed. So I installed ceres-solver over homebrew.

With QT I added all the libraries and headers like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/eigen3/ \
/usr/local/Cellar/ceres-solver/HEAD-202dd9f_4/include/ \
/usr/local/include/OpencvHeader/
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/ceres-solver/HEAD-202dd9f_4/lib -lceres
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_sfm ...
```

Because I still have the same problem I am thinking I did something wrong by loading the Headers or Libs and I hope someone here can help me with this problem.

OR how can I else get CERES_FOUND to be true?

Comment: See if this helps: http://answers.opencv.org/question/140181/reconstruct-is-not-a-member-of-cvsfm/

Comment: Not really. I am getting a new error: no member named 'type' in cv::DataType<std::_1::basic_string<char>>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sture what i took now all to solve the problem. But in one case the answer from p-a-o-l-o was helping. Because sometime ceres-solver doesn't get loaded if the version is a newer one or something. So i defined

```
#define CERES_FOUND true
```

bevor I included

```
#include<opencv2/sfm.hpp>
```

Also I added the define

```
#define OPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_DEPRECATED
```

before all that. And the last thing, was that the example they where showing, is not working anymore. I tried to load my images with a vector of strings like this:

```
    bool is_projective = true;
    vector<Mat> Rs_est, ts_est, points3d_estimated;
    Matx33d K = Matx33d(f, 0, cx,
                        0, f, cy,
                        0, 0, 1);

    std::vector<string> images_paths;    
    reconstruct(images_paths, Rs_est, ts_est, K, points3d_estimated, is_projective);
```

And somehow it makes an error. There is also en correct version of this example you can find [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/5e4d9b0be74b86db56af18075632ee201e027926/modules/sfm/samples/scene_reconstruction.cpp). Where it shows that they are not using string but String.

I am not sture why the other string type made problems, but since then it worked for me. So the correct code is:

```
        std::vector<String> images_paths;    
        reconstruct(images_paths, Rs_est, ts_est, K, points3d_estimated, is_projective);
```